# Getting the selected option value (NOT text) from dropdown with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a dropdown like so:

```
<select id="dropdownList">
  <option val="1">Item One</option>
  <option val="2">Item Two</option>
  <option val="3">Item Three</option>
</select>
```

When I use **$('#dropdownList').val()**, the value returned is "Item One/Two/Three" rather than the actual option value (1/2/3), which is what I need. I'm not sure if I should be using something other than .val()? I apologize if this has been answered somewhere, but my Google-fu is failing me on this one.

Comment: I realize that you're new here, so I'll introduce you to you could accept the answer that you feel best answered the question and earn an additional 2 rep to go along with the 6 you have now ;) ~ check the arrow under the votes on the left side of the page.

Comment: Thanks, I attempted to do that, was told to wait 41 seconds, and then...nothing happened? EDIT: Apologies, it apparently worked, though it didn't light up right away.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change your html to the valid `value=` instead of `val=`

Comment: +1 Thanks for this.  I was banging my head against the wall, and this made me relize I had typo'd `vlaue` instead of `value`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
<select id="dropdownList">
  <option value="1">Item One</option>
  <option value="2">Item Two</option>
  <option value="3">Item Three</option> <!-- this works -->
  <option val="3">Item Three</option>   <!-- this is what you HAD before -->
</select>
```

Or if that's not an option, then get the selected index and look for the `$(this).attr('val')`

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
$('#dropdownList option:selected').attr('val')
```

note : didnt tested

Comment: You should test in the future, it works wonders, but +1 for the use of `attr('val')` cos it would work too ;)